# ADD MORE option in form element

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I am working with WEBFORM module, and I provided only one text area for the user to enter his choice but I want a "ADD MORE" button in my form element so that my user can enter his second choice also. I want to know what I can do to achieve described action?

Comment: I think you'll have to code it manually, there's nothing in core to help with that and I've never seen a contrib module that'll do it (that would be one very popular module I think)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at the moment with Webform, but hey, do you really need a webform module to achieve what you need?

You could create a custom content type with any fields set you can imagine (single and multiple) and give users permission to create nodes of this type. So this way you'd be able to gather form submissions as separate nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to use [Webform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module (presuming you're using webform module version prior to 7.x-4.x which is still in alpha).

Instead of having a "add more" button, you could have a "add more" checkbox, and when this checkbox is checked, Webform Conditional would display your second textarea...